# How would I set a checkbox to activate a link in a wordpress blog?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I want to be able to let people download stuff from the blog, like code for people to use.  But I want to make sure people read the "License/Copyright" stuff before hand.  It would say something like, "Check to agree to terms and conditions" and when they click it the download link is activated.

Bonus: records their IP address from where they downloaded it, and the time when they downloaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you could do something like this:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        window.location.href = "/url/to/download";
    }
    else {
        // error handling
    }
})
```

If you're not using jQuery let me know and I'll whip up a pure Javascript example.

Comment: Sorry, no jQuery.  I suppose I could add it in, I'm just very new and inexperienced with these sorts of things.